# Bug creates lines in the answer box when editing my answers

Tags: discussion, bug

When I go to edit the code section of a long answer of mine, I get these annoying lines popping up when I scroll up or down:

[image: Screenshot of answer box with gray horizontal lines on top of three fourths of the text.]

This can make editing my answer a real pain sometimes. In this picture they're gray, but sometimes they're blue and lining up right over my words as well. Is this a documented bug or some sort of feature that I'm not understanding?

To reproduce the blue lines, click in the box and scroll down. It creates these lines every time. A huge pain when editing!

[image: Screenshot of answer box with blue horizontal lines on top of the text.]

[image: The error happens in Internet Explorer 11 Version: 11.0.9600.18697 Update Versions: 11.0.43 (KB4021558).]

[image: The browser is running on Windows edition Windows 7 Enterprise (64-bit) Service Pack 1.]

Comment: And OS / Version? Did you update your display drivers recently? Or not updated them in a while?

Comment: This is my office computer and I don't have administrative privileges to update my drivers, but they're pretty on top of this stuff so I'd be surprised if they were that outdated.

Comment: Still - looks like a browser/display issue, which is completely out of our control here. This isn't something we can fix.

Comment: So what kind of note should I make to my IT guys, that I need a new monitor?

Comment: The problem isn't the monitor - it is the graphics card.

Comment: In the future, please don't post screenshots of text (the browser/OS images). Just put the text into your post.

Comment: I wasn't sure what was important to include so instead of typing out all the lines of information I just decided to use screen grabs.

Comment: Sure but all anyone who can't view those images would have seen was "MyBrowser" and "OS", which doesn't tell them anything.